# What was Country Herb Chicken Sauce Blend?

Tags: substitutions, sauce, spices, recipe-reverse-engineering

An old hand-written recipe calls for one package of "Country Herb Chicken Sauce Blend", a presumably retired McCormick product. The recipe is quite similar to this one:

https://www.cookingindex.com/recipes/38300/country-pot-pie.htm

Whatever was in this packet, it seems it was designed to be mixed with water and milk and brought to a boil to make a sauce.

We'd love to re-create the recipe. Does anyone know what was in that packet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The McCormick website has a recipe for ["Country Herb Chicken and Dumplings."](https://www.mccormick.com/recipes/main-dishes/country-herb-chicken-and-dumplings)  That might be a good starting point.

[Here is someone else's recipe for the spice mix.](https://www.budget101.com/recipes/4351-country-herb-chicken-seasoning-mix/)

[It looks like you can still get the McCormick spice blend, here, for example.](https://www.instacart.com/products/74987-mccormick-recipe-inspirations-country-herb-chicken-dumplings-pre-measured-spices-recipe-card-0-17-oz)

These products are not a "just add water" solution, but you can probably get reasonably close between the recipe and spice mixes.

Comment: Nice! I'll bet it was the spice blend plus some amount of flour. Thanks!